# Облачная ОС для загрузки на хостинг

Tags: облако, ос

Есть ли в свободном доступе Облачные ОСи, по типу UNET.com или iCloud, но для установки на свой хостинг?

UPD: с возможностью модернизации исходного кода и дописывания своих приложений например на JS

Answer (score 1):

[eyeOS](http://www.eyeos.org/) . Написана на php + js. Код открыт, так что возможно дописывание своих компонентов системы.

Answer (score 0):

ChromeOS. Наверное не совсем то о чем вы говорите, но по сути идея та же. Минимум ПО на компьютере, все приложения в браузере. Еще ExpressGate подходящая технология.

Comment: Да, это не совсем то. Нужно что бы от стационара вообще никак не зависело, полный интернет. Что бы с любого компа можно было попасть